# Lagom Serialization for Static Assets

Tags: serialization, lagom

I'm developing a Lagom microservice. In addition to its meat, it has a few static files to serve (index.html, *.css, *.js, and favicon.ico). I know how to set the response's Content-Type header using Lagom's `ServerServiceCall[Req, Res]`. However, if if specify `String` as the response parameter type, Content-Type is overwritten as "text/plain" regardless of what I set in the service call's body. If I use `akka.util.ByteString`, then Content-Type becomes "application/octet-stream".

I figure this must be because this is what the serializers of `String` and `ByteString` demand. So, my question is: which response types should I do to obtain "text/html", "text/css", "application/javascript", and "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"? Or is there a more generic way to serve static assets in Lagom? The documentation is surprisingly sparse on this.

Would something like this work:

```
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.transport.MessageProtocol
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.deser.MessageSerializer.NegotiatedSerializer

class ContentTypeSerializer(contentType: String, charset: String) extends NegotiatedSerializer[String, ByteString] {
  override val protocol = MessageProtocol(Some(contentType), Some(charset))
  def serialize(body: String) = ByteString.fromString(body, charset)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this takes care of it:

```
import akka.util.ByteString
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.transport._
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.deser.StrictMessageSerializer
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.api.deser.MessageSerializer.{NegotiatedDeserializer, NegotiatedSerializer}

class ContentTypeSerializer(contentType: String, charset: String) extends NegotiatedSerializer[String, ByteString] {
  override val protocol = MessageProtocol(Some(contentType), Some(charset))
  def serialize(body: String) = ByteString.fromString(body, charset)
}

object ContentTypeSerializer {
  val Json = "application/json"
  val Js = "application/javascript"
  val Icon = "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
  val Html = "text/html"
  val Css = "text/css"

  val JsonSerializer = new ContentTypeSerializer(ContentTypeSerializer.Json, "utf-8")
}

class JsonTextDeserializer extends NegotiatedDeserializer[String, ByteString] {
  def deserialize(bytes: ByteString) =
    try {
      Json.parse(bytes.iterator.asInputStream).as[String]
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => throw DeserializationException(e)
    }
}

object ResponseSerializer extends StrictMessageSerializer[String] {
  override val acceptResponseProtocols = List(
    MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Json)),
    MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Html)),
    MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Icon)),
    MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Css)),
    MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Js))
  )

  val serializerForRequest = ContentTypeSerializer.JsonSerializer

  def deserializer(protocol: MessageProtocol) = protocol.contentType match {
    case Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Json) | None =>
      new JsonTextDeserializer
    case _ =>
      throw UnsupportedMediaType(protocol, MessageProtocol(Some("text/plain")))
  }

  def serializerForResponse(accepted: immutable.Seq[MessageProtocol]) = accepted match {
    case Nil => ContentTypeSerializer.JsonSerializer
    case protocols => protocols.collectFirst {
      case MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Json), charset, _) =>
        new ContentTypeSerializer(ContentTypeSerializer.Json, charset.getOrElse("utf-8"))
      case MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Html), charset, _) =>
        new ContentTypeSerializer(ContentTypeSerializer.Html, charset.getOrElse("utf-8"))
      case MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Icon), charset, _) =>
        new ContentTypeSerializer(ContentTypeSerializer.Icon, charset.getOrElse("utf-8"))
      case MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Css), charset, _) =>
        new ContentTypeSerializer(ContentTypeSerializer.Css, charset.getOrElse("utf-8"))
      case MessageProtocol(Some(ContentTypeSerializer.Js), charset, _) =>
        new ContentTypeSerializer(ContentTypeSerializer.Js, charset.getOrElse("utf-8"))
    }.getOrElse {
      throw NotAcceptable(accepted, MessageProtocol(Some("text/plain")))
    }
  }
}
```